# How do I print the screen layout in Visual Studio 2012 (Windows Forms)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a complex form that I created in Visual Studio 2012; I want to print out that form exactly as it shows in the designer using Visual Studio 2012 (not while the program/form is running).  Is this possible?

I know I can just do a screen shot, but I will need to be doing this quite often and would prefer a simple, direct way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's anything within visual studios that does exactly what you're suggesting.

I would definitely recommend snagit. We use it at work quite a bit when putting together internal documentation.

http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html

You just click and drag and it saves everything in one location. You can also do a quick click on the title bar of the vs window and it will save a screenshot of everything within that window. It's a lot easier than constantly pressing the print button and then pasting it somewhere.

Or you could write your own program that does exactly what you need it to do.